# jQuery/javascript : how to accept special chars and send it through ajax using json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, character-encoding, special-characters

I tried btoa()

```
btoa("Chars to encode");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knaa74ud/1/)

But it doesnot work properly with mobile characters

I used `encodeURIComponent()` also but it makes string `LONG` and json has 256 chars limitation on sending data so it is issue .

What would be correct solution for it ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all json is not limited to 256 symbols. I suppose you are sending your data by GET method - it has limited length and could prevent you to sent special chars.

The solucion could me to use POST method in place of GET.
Just use:

```
jQuery.post('http://you-url-here',{
    'data': 'string-with-special-chars',
    ....
},function(res){ ... },'json');
```

or almost the same using jQuery.ajax() method.

Comment: string with special chars doesnt work as it contais & , so it takes as query string

Comment: Sending them by POST will permit you to use '&' symbol